# Bulk insert statement with unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert, unique-constraint

I am writing a PHP script where I need to generate unique codes. These codes are generated by an admin user, 100K at a time. I have an algorithm that generates the code, but there is a very slight chance a duplicate will get into the mix - something like 0.001% chance but still it could cause a problem.

I am looking to run a bulk insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO coupons ( 'code' ) VALUES ('code1'),('code2'),('code3');
```

This will have 100K codes in it. What I want to know is if all of them are unique except lets say code100 will the insert stop at that code or will it continue on for the rest of the inserts and let me know by a warning.

If it will end up failing at the first duplicate, what can I do about it? Performance isn't a big issue as its an admin area and I can spin the process off until its completed.

Comment: I ended up creating a class to make a check against the codes generated and then inserting only the unique ones then starting the process again until the amount was satisfied. In terms of performance its good as it can easily insert a couple of million records in the background without the public site feeling strain.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Could you please elaborate on how you went about doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a duplicate found in the bulk insert, the *entire* insert will fail -- not just everything after the duplicate.  If performance is not an issue and it doesn't matter if you lose some of the inserts, you could just do each `INSERT` statement individually.  Otherwise, update your algorithm to check for duplicates when it generates the codes.

Comment: Yeah I could do that. Performance isn't a **big** issue, but it would be if an admin asks for 100K codes I can't have the script hitting the DB at least 100k times.